# Strip file from path PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell Script that finds all log4j jar files on a system. I want to separate the values out of the found paths based on just `path`, `filename`, and `version`.

For example, if I have a returned path of `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.14.1\log4j-core-2.14.1.jar`, how can I get:

**Just the path -** `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.14.1\`

**Just the file -** `log4j-core-2.14.1.jar`

**Just the version -** `2.14.1`

Comment: Have you considered using `Split-Path`?

Comment: Looking at the docs now.

Comment: It does the trick for the first two, but what about the version regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use `Get-ChildItem` for that.

```
$Item = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.14.1\log4j-core-2.14.1.jar'

# Folder containing the file
$Item.PSParentPath

# Filename
$Item.Name

# Version extracted from the Parent path
# As string
($ITem.PSParentPath.Split('\'))[-1]
# As System.Version object
[Version]($ITem.PSParentPath.Split('\'))[-1]
```

Or, using `Split-Path`

```
$FullPath = 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.14.1\log4j-core-2.14.1.jar'
$Filename = Split-Path -Path $FullPath -Leaf
$ParentPath = Split-Path -Path $FullPath -Parent
# Version from Parent path
$Version = $ParentPath.Split('\')[-1]
```

**Bonus**

This is unnecessary since you can get the version straight from the path but if the path was not formatted in such a way, you could extract the version from the filename in the following way.

```
$Version = $Filename -replace 'log4j-core-(.*).jar', '$1'
```

**Bonus #2**

Let's say you want to be proactive with the possible filename change, you could then parse the extracted version into a `System.Version` object to make sure you are getting something that make sense.

```
$Version = $null
if (![Version]::TryParse(($Filename -replace 'log4j-core-(.*).jar', '$1'),[ref]$Version)) {
    Write-Warning 'Version could not be parsed from the filename'
} else {
    Write-Host "Version is $Version"
}
```

That would ensure that you indeed have a version of something. and not a different string (this would only happen if they suddently changed the filename to something else).